# Maven Artifactory skip ssl certification

Tags: java, windows, maven, ssl-certificate, artifactory

My company was using Nexus as repository but now it changed to Artifactory.
When I try to build with maven even using this all options

- `Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure=true`
- `Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.allowall=true`
- `Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.ignore.validity.dates=true`

it fails with the error

> PKIX path building failed unable to find valid certification path to
>   request target

I am using Maven version 3.3.9 and JAVA_HOME = JDK 1.8.072. Running the build with -X option this is some relevant information that it log

Using transporter `WagonTransporter` with priority -1.0 for https://....
Using connector `BasicRepositoryConnector` with priority 0.0 for https://...  with username=xxx ,password=***

> Failed to read artifact descriptor Validator PKIX path building failed
>   SunCertPathBuilderException unable to find valid certification path to
>   request target

Comment: Is your Artifactory server configured with an SSL certificate, even a self signed one, or does not have SSL enabled at all?

Comment: It is configured with an SSL certificate

Comment: Do you manage to use other tools such a cURL to download from Artifactory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved it.
[jfrog KB](https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/how-to-resolve-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requested-target-error/)

1. If it is older Artifactory 6.x, it is using outside JVM and you can find the enabled one using

   /usr/sbin/alternatives --config java
2. If the version is 7.x. The JDK is bundled inside **$JF_PRODUCT_HOME/app/third-party/java**

Import your Root Certificate via keytool command given in the KB